# Hiding a row in a table with a query when 3 columns have null values

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am looking for the best way to build a query which would hide the record (row) in the event that three field values (in three different columns) would be null. The code below is giving me a syntax run time error message of 3075. Also, I am not sure if it is causing a problem but the code below is executed from a main form and impacting the subform frmStaticDataSkills02.

```
sql_get = "SELECT [tblCompetency02].[HighLevelObjective], [tblCompetency04].[Self], [tblCompetency04].[SelfSpecialLanguage], [tblCompetency04].[SelfChecklist], [tblCompetency04].[Team], [tblCompetency04].[TeamSpecialLanguage], [tblCompetency04].[TeamChecklist], [tblCompetency04].[Organisation], [tblCompetency04].[OrganisationSpecialLanguage], [tblCompetency04].[OrganisationChecklist], [tblCompetency02].[Competency] FROM [tblCompetency04] INNER JOIN [tblCompetency02] ON [tblCompetency04].[HighLevelObjective] = [tblCompetency02].[ID] WHERE ([tblcompetency04].[self]<>"" or [tblcompetency04].[team]<>"" or [tblcompetency04].[organisation]<>"")"
Form_frmStaticDataSkills02.Form.RecordSource = sql_get
```

Comment: `select ... where not (col1 is null and col2 is null and col3 is null)`

Comment: Thank you. I think we are on the right track. Can you please check my edited code which currently is giving me a run time 424 error message.  (Object necessary)

Comment: The syntax looks ok, this error might be related to some specifics in Access...

Comment: I should of highlighted that I am trying to update a sub form from a main form. Could you please look at my code again?  I Think my issue now lies with the referencing and not the syntax of the query.

Comment: I can't help you, I don't have a clue about forms in Access :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return the data if not all three columns are NULL:

```
where not (col1 is null and col2 is null and col3 is null)
```

This is the same after applying algebra of logic: return the row if any of the three rows is NOT NULL

```
where col1 is not null or col2 is not null or col3 is not null)
```

Answer (score 2):

In a general sense, in a table of N columns, you can explicitly count the number of NULL columns in a table and then add them up and compare the count of nulls to `3` in a where predicate:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable x
WHERE 
     ((IIF(x.COL1 IS NULL, 1 , 0) + 
       IIF(x.COL2 IS  NULL, 1 , 0) + 
       IIF(x.COL3 IS  NULL, 1 , 0) + 
       IIF(x.COL4 IS  NULL, 1 , 0))) <> 3;
```

(Obviously, keep adding `IIF` statements for all N columns of the table

Answer (score 1):

End your query with:

```
WHERE [column_1] IS NOT NULL AND [column_2] IS NOT NULL AND [column_3] IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: I dont think so. What happens if ONE of the columns is null ??  Using your query, it seems that all columns need to be poplulated otherwise the record will not be recognised?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in your where clause by specifying that all 3 fields should not be NULL, the result set that is returned will not have records where all 3 fields are NULL.

```
SELECT * 
FROM tablename
WHERE
field1 IS NOT NULL AND
field2 IS NOT NULL AND
field3 IS NOT NULL
```

If you do not want to have rows returned where any one of the columns has null values you would use `OR`. For example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tablename
WHERE
field1 IS NOT NULL OR
field2 IS NOT NULL OR
field3 IS NOT NULL
```